# Setting a height of container, while content doesn't have specified height - only padding

Tags: html, css, grid, height, padding

I can not think of a solution. I’ve got many square divs like this:
width=padding-bottom=16,6%

It is making a nice grid on a screen with many (72) squares. Inside of each is a background property with an image.

The thing is that I also have a fixed bottom stripe and my problem is, that it’s overlapping the last row of the grid.

How can I set the margin-bottom to it? There is no specified height of the divs.

I’ve tried to put it all in a div, but it thinks that the height of content is 0.

The code below, thanks for any ideas.

HTML:

```
<div class="homemade-container">
<div class="square img_1-2"> </div>
THERE IS 72 DIVS LIKE THIS ONE, JUST WITH DIFFERENT SECOND CLASS NUMBER (BACKGROUND IMAGE)
</div>
<div class="lowermenu">
CONTENT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homemade-container{
    padding-bottom:75px;
}
.square{
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.45%;
    padding-bottom : 16.45%;
    margin:0.1%;
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.img_1-2{
    background-image:url('../portfolio/www/www24.jpg');
}
.lowermenu{
    color:#d4d4d4;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#2b2b2b;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a margin to the last div via CSS:

```
div[class~='square']:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

Comment: :last-of-type will not work with classes as you want it to (it only works with elements), but your thought helped me anyway. Thank you for unblocking my mind :) I just added .last class to the last div and added a margin-bottom to it. Thanks once again!

Comment: Actually you are right according to the documentation it can only be used with attribute selector in that respect. Though I made a quick fiddle and actually using it on class element works. https://jsfiddle.net/bkpLybkp/ That shouldn't work should it?

Comment: Hm you're right, it works in your fiddle, when I tried it with my files it was not. Maybe this is just an over-interpretation of the fiddle itself, rather than validate code?

Comment: Not sure, also worked with latest Crome version when I tried it with .html and .css file. Maybe it is a webkit behaviour?